# Reactjs unseen components

Tags: reactjs

This is my main page :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import navBar from './navigationBar';

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <navBar/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Main;
```

And here is navBar component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Error from './Error'

class navigationBar extends React.Component  {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="nav">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/data"} className="nav-link"> Data </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/analysis"} className="nav-link"> Analysis </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/Monitor"} className="nav-link"> Monitor </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <Route path={"/webiks/:user"} component={Error}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default navigationBar;
```

For some reason I cant see the navigationBar components.
is this problem related to the code or to the configurations?

Thank you.

Comment: [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT !!**

As @Andrew state: the root cause is your class name `class navigationBar`. Change it to `class NavigationBar` and export it correctly should fix it export default NavigationBar;`

---

`export default navigationBar;`

You are exporting with `navigationBar` by default. Please update the import:

`import navigationBar from './navigationBar';`

And

`<div className="container">
  <navigationBar/>
</div>`

Comment: Export default will work even if he will importing like this 
`import Sdaskfhasdf from './navigationBar';` and in `Sdaskfhasdf` we will have an exported component.

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you. Since the owner has marked this one as the answer, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`navigationBar` should be with a capital letter -> `NavigationBar`

All components should be with a capital letter. If a component with a small letter, it is perceived as if the component is a tag.